# Make a copy of the first x characters in a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

What is the best / easiest way of duplicating a column in a dataframe but to only keep the first x characters of the value.
e.g.

```
Column 1   New_Column
abcdef      abcd
bbhhsb      bbhh
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `substr`

```
df1$New_Column <- substr(df1$Column1, 1, 4)
```

---

Or with `sub`

```
df1$New_Column <- sub("^(....).*", "\\1", df1$Column1)
```